# How to insert multiple values in single cell database table in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an android database application in which i have to add multiple values in single cell of database table like

```
id| col 1     | col2     |
  | 1,2,3,4   | a,b,c,d  |
  | 1,1,1,1   | ,x,x,x,x |
  |           |          |
```

i have created the database in SQLite Database Browser

how can i achieve this

Comment: Insert as a string from Java, use join if you have those in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the data that you'd like to load into that cell, for example into xml, json, or maybe csv if that suits you. Xml could get a bit messy, for json there's the Gson lib that makes things really easy, and csv is quite straighforward if your data is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON and store it as a String. I would want to seriously take a look why you want to do that though